# tensorflow weight constraint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a huge dataset that is actually created by using an equation with four unknowns. Which means:

```
A*x_1 + B*x_2 + C*x_3 + D*x_4 = y
```

I have values of `x = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]` and `y`.
I need to find values of A, B, C, D using neural networks.

I created a (4,1) random weights matrix by using

```
W = tf.random_uniform((4,1), minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float64, seed=None, name=None)
```

Now, all elements of weights are between 0 and 1. However, what I need is, having these weights as their sum is equal to one no matter which iteration is.

For example, weights can be 0.25, 0.45, 0.15, 0.15 at start. After 1000 iteration weights can be updated as 0.33, 0.25, 0.42, 0.00 or 1.00, 0, 0, 0.

As far as I read, softmax function is suitable for the operation. Yet, I wasn't be able to integrate softmax function as constraint.

Second question:

I try to build a model by modifying this one. 
https://medium.com/@liccowee/tensorflow-to-solve-simple-math-equation-27f42a44f0f1

```
x = tf.Variable(X_train)
y = tf.Variable(y_train[0])

yy = tf.matmul(x, W)
deviation = tf.square (y-yy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(deviation)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(50000):
        sess.run(train_step)

    print(sess.run(W))
```

However, each time it result differently and result does not hold. Not even close.
For example:

```
y = 0.680084169  
x = [(0.764845252)      (0.68613559) (0.358461678) (0.680084169)]
```

result of two different model have weights

```
(0.63843704)    (0.12227005)    (0.42270223)    (0.05195979)  
(0.45886127)    (0.88964135)    (0.59473092)    (0.19037153)
```

and estimation of first one is 0.759058953
estimation of second one is 1.304029364.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

To implement the constraint of `sum( X ) = 1` you can do either of two things. You can train for three `x`s and for the fourth use `1 - sum( X )`. Alternatively, you can divide `X` by `sum( X )` before you do the multiplication. (This is similar to what [`tf.nn.softmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) does, but it was designed for a specific purpose (to process logit inputs) and it takes the *exponent* of `X` before the operation. So if you want to use softmax for this, you'd have to first take the `log` of `X`, which is just added complexity (you say your `X`s are between 0 and 1, you'd also have an issue with 0s).) That is:

```
X = X / tf.reduce_sum( X )
```

will set the sum of `X` to one by scaling all the values. (It is unclear from your question whether it's `X` or `W` you want to set to sum to one, change the line above to match your intentions.)

I presume "results don't hold" you mean that your "network" is not converging. There are two reasons for that. First, you might want to reduce the learning rate.

The second is, unfortunately, a theoretical issue with your original problem. You're taking the linear combination of 4 numbers and trying to find the coefficients to get a certain result. The issue is that the problem is underconstrained. Basically you can arbitrarily fix 2 of the 4 numbers, and you can find a thrid and fourth one to satisfy the equality; well, for a lot of values at least. (Since you want `X`s between 0 and 1, there could be `Y`s that are outside of the possible range, or right on the edge.) Depending on what you want exactly, you might want to add a L2 regularization constraint (aka weight decay), like this:

```
deviation = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square ( y - yy ) ) + 0.004 * tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( x ) )
```

where 0.004 would be the coefficient for weight decay, you need to experiment finding the best value.

Also an implementation issue is that

```
y = tf.Variable(y_train[0])
```

looks like you're setting up `y` as a trainable variable with [`tf.Variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), so the training process will also change your `y` which is probably not something you want. You probably want something like

```
t = tf.Variable( y_train[ 0 ], trainable = False )
```

Comment: Can't we implement a custom [`Constraint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/constraints/Constraint)? I'm not sure if something like this could work: `w * equal(sum(w), 1.0)` (see [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/constraints/Constraint))

Comment: @StefanFalk Possibly, maybe the UnitNorm. I wrote this answer in 2018, four years ago, when constraints were not available yet.